# Is it possible without regex to separate log string into variables for desired pattern?

Tags: java, parsing, logging

i'm asking if it's possible to separate .log line to variable as it was done to construct a .log file. Let me explain :

As it shows on : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Combined Log format :

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
```

I have to make this with Java:

Sample line:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [03/Jul/2017:09:05:56 +0000] "GET /index.php?route=journal2/assets/css&j2v=2.7.6 HTTP/1.1" xxx xxx "http://xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx/index.php?route=product/search&search=asus" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.90 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.91.867.38"
```

**I need to separate this string to** :

- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- short stroke
- short stroke
- [03/Jul/2017:09:05:56 +0000]
- "GET /index,php?route=journal2/assets/css&j2v=2.7.6 HTTP/1.1"
- xxx
- xxx
- "xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx/index.php?route=product/search&search=asus"
  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.90 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.91.867.38"

Got the idea? How can i make it without regex? 
P.S. it will get like hundreds of lines, so any ideas how to process them like that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: I can't use it, i was told not to use that, to make it harder.

Comment: I don't want that to be done, i want ideas how to make that. Because i'm new at java and trying to understand everything. The attempts are zero at the moment, i was figuring out how should i start doing this.

Comment: I do not expect that. I want only suggestions and better ideas to make it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string class has methods such as [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) which you can use to *manually* "search" a string for specific "separators". To then use methods like [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to fetch, well substrings.

In other words: it is absolutely possible to write your own very specific parsing code that extracts values from a string.

But that means trying to re-invent an existing wheel; knowing that your attempts will cost a lot of time, and the outcome will be most likely incomplete and break on the very first log line you didn't anticipate.

And when I get your question right, you want to be able to provide a "format" such as: `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""` that is then somehow used to dissect the log lines. Sorry - that is **exactly** what you use regular expressions for. So again: your approach boils down to inventing and implementing your own regex language and engine. Of course this is possible, but a waste of time.

Beyond that, consider this task to be **very advanced**. This is *nothing* a newbie can think of doing in reasonable amounts of time. Instead: spend your energy to learn to apply *existing*, well-proven, well-tested technology. In such situations, that is the way to go (also from a **business** perspective - anything else is also a *waste* of **money**).

And assuming this is for "learning purposes" - then the first paragraph tells you where to start. But beyond that:

- you have to first define your own "pattern language"
- then you have to implement a *parser* for such formats
- then you have to implement an engine that takes parsed formats as input and matches them onto input strings

As said: possible, but a *ton* of **hard** work.

Comment: Thanks, for answer. But is it possible to make something similar to LogFormat as it mentioned above? Because i'm planning to use Configuration file such as json that will have file format which it has to use.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i will have to tell them that this is just a waste of time, that i have to you regex. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The point is: it is **a lot** of work. And in case the idea is to use this for anything else than a *learning product* (meaning: it is not "throw away code") then inventing your own wheel is the less optimal strategy.